# Spring Boot layer architecture rest validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to validate on my spring boot project but
I get the error right when I access the repository from the controls.

CustomerController.java

```
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;



@PostMapping("/addcustomer")
public Customer addCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer) {
    return customerRepository.save(customer);
    
}
```

when i use layered architecture i get the error on the console

CustomerController.java

```
@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;


    

@PostMapping("/addcustomer")
public Customer addCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody CustomerDto customer) {
    return customerService.save(customer);
    
}
```

Customer.java

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

@Id
private String nickName;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2 , max = 20 , message = "Incorret name")
private String name;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2 , max = 20 , message = "Incorret surname")
private String surname;

@NotBlank
@Email
private String e_mail;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 6, max = 20, message = "Your password should be at least 6 character")
private String password;

@NotNull
private long balance;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
@Nullable
private Car car;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer")
private Accept accept;



public Customer() {
}

public Customer(String nickName, String name, String surname, String e_mail, String password, long balance, Car car) {
    super();
    this.nickName = nickName;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.e_mail = e_mail;
    this.password = password;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.car = car;
}

public String getNickName() {
    return nickName;
}

public void setNickName(String nickName) {
    this.nickName = nickName;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getE_mail() {
    return e_mail;
}

public void setE_mail(String e_mail) {
    this.e_mail = e_mail;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public long getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(long balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public Car getCar() {
    return car;
}

public void setCar(Car car) {
    this.car = car;
}

}
```

CustomerDto.java

```
public class CustomerDto {

private String nickName;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String e_mail;
private String password;
private long balance;
@Nullable
private long carID;


public String getNickName() {
    return nickName;
}
public void setNickName(String nickName) {
    this.nickName = nickName;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
public String getE_mail() {
    return e_mail;
}
public void setE_mail(String e_mail) {
    this.e_mail = e_mail;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public long getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public void setBalance(long balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
public long getCarID() {
    return carID;
}
public void setCarID(long carID) {
    this.carID = carID;
}
public CustomerDto() {
    super();
}
public CustomerDto(String nickName, String name, String surname, String e_mail, String password, long balance,
        long carID) {
 
    this.nickName = nickName;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.e_mail = e_mail;
    this.password = password;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.carID = carID;
}


}
```

CustomerServiceImpl.java

```
@Override
public Customer save(CustomerDto customerdto){
    try {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        convertToEntity(customer, customerdto);

        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
    
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    
    
}
```

CustomerService.java

```
public interface CustomerService {

public Customer save(CustomerDto customerDto);

public void update(CustomerDto customerDto);

public void delete();

public void convertToDto(Customer customer, CustomerDto customerDto);

public void convertToEntity(Customer customer, CustomerDto customerDto);

public List<CustomerDto> customerList();

 
public ResponseEntity<CustomerDto> findByUserName(String nickName) throws ResourceNotFoundException;

}
```

CustomerRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long>
```

GlobalExceptionHandler.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> resourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request){
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);             
}


@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> globalExceptionHandler(Exception ex, WebRequest request){
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(),ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}


@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> customValidationErrorHanding(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception){
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), "Validation Error!",
            exception.getBindingResult().getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}


 }
```

ErrorDetails.java

```
public class ErrorDetails {
public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
    super();
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
}
public Date getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}
public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}
public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}
private Date timestamp;
private String message;
private String details;


}
```

SpringRentApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringRentApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringRentApplication.class, args);
}

 }
```

There is no error with my GlobalExceptionHandler.java and ErrorDetail.java  codes. I already said that when I access the repositor from the controller it works correctly.

Console

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:571)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy531.save(Unknown Source)
at com.godoro.springRent.business.impl.CustomerServiceImpl.save(CustomerServiceImpl.java:56)
at com.godoro.springRent.presentation.rest.NewCustomerController.addCustomer(NewCustomerController.java:32)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: Post proper (error) logs. have you annotated your service class as `@Transactional` ?

Comment: It gives a validation error in the log. For example, the password must have at least 6 characters. 
When I add a transaction I get the following error "message": "Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction" @Ashutosh

Comment: It's behaving as expected. Provide valid field value in request as defined in Entity class

Comment: When I access the repositor from the controller, I get the error like: {
    "timestamp": "2020-12-28T21:49:00.084+00:00",
    "message": "Validation Error!",
    "details": "Your password should be at least 6 character"
}    i mean I want to get the same message when I use layered architecture @Ashutosh

Comment: `I get the error` what is "the error" i see no error, no log, no stacktrace no nothing. Update your question with current behaviour with proper error logs including stack traces. And also expected behaviour. Voted to close

Comment: I am not getting an error. when i use layered architecture i see the Validation error on the console @Toerktumlare

Comment: if you are not getting an error, we cant help you, post all relevant logs, because the information you have provided is not enough, read what i wrote, errors, LOGS, stacktraces, how to reproduce, how you make your request, postman, curl, etc

Comment: i added errors @Toerktumlare

Comment: When you say console, it's the log data. Please post your entire project with relevant files  including `Customer` and complete error log. Or link to your github repo if any.

Comment: i added all code @Ashutosh

Comment: thank you. The main problem is that I should have done the control operations in CustomerDto, not in the entity. @Ashutosh

Comment: Recommended way is to create your request/response views, set service a s transactional, call service from controller and then use repo from service for persistence. The link to github repo is `github.com/ashutosh049/customer-service-demo`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to catch validation errors at binding time when the controller gets a request. To do that, you must add validation tags in your CustomerDTO object. Doing so, you'll be able to catch binding errors like this:

```
@PostMapping("/addcustomer")
public Customer addCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody CustomerDto customer, BindingResult theBindingResult) {

    if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()){
             //Do something here, like returning the view that has the form to create a new customer
    }
    return customerService.save(customer);
    
}
```